# Creating a data set with paired data and converting it into a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, missing-data

So, I'm using R to try and do a phylogenetic PCA on a dataset that I have using the phyl.pca function from the phytools package.  However, I'm having issues organising my data in a way that the function will accept!  And that's not all: I did a bit of experimenting and I know that there are more issues further down the line, which I will get into...

Getting straight to the issue, here's the data frame (with dummy data) that I'm using:

```
>all
                  Taxa Tibia Feather
1          Microraptor 138   101
2          Microraptor 139   114
3          Microraptor 145   141
4           Anchiornis 160   81
5           Anchiornis 14    NA
6        Archaeopteryx 134   82
7        Archaeopteryx 136   71
8        Archaeopteryx 132   NA
9        Archaeopteryx 14    NA
10 Scansoriopterygidae 120   85
11 Scansoriopterygidae 116   NA
12 Scansoriopterygidae 123   NA
13           Sapeornis 108   NA
14           Sapeornis 112   86
15           Sapeornis 118   NA
16           Sapeornis 103   NA
17      Confuciusornis 96    NA
18      Confuciusornis 107   30
19      Confuciusornis 148   33
20      Confuciusornis 128   61
```

The taxa are arranged into a tree (called "tree") with Microraptor being the most basal and then progressing in order through to Confuciusornis:

```
>summary(tree)

Phylogenetic tree: tree 

  Number of tips: 6 
  Number of nodes: 5 
  Branch lengths:
    mean: 1 
    variance: 0 
    distribution summary:
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median 3rd Qu.    Max. 
      1       1       1       1       1 
  No root edge.
  Tip labels: Confuciusornis 
              Sapeornis
              Scansoriopterygidae
              Archaeopteryx
              Anchiornis
              Microraptor
  No node labels.
```

And the function:

```
>phyl.pca(tree, all, method="BM", mode="corr")
```

And this is the error that is coming up:

```
Error in phyl.pca(tree, all, method = "BM", mode = "corr") : 
number of rows in Y cannot be greater than number of taxa in your tree
```

Y being the "all" data frame.  So I have 6 taxa in my tree (matching the 6 taxa in the data frame) but there are 20 rows in my data frame.  So I used this function:

```
> all_agg <- aggregate(all[,-1],by=list(all$Taxa),mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

And got this:

```
              Group.1 Tibia Feather
1          Anchiornis   153      81
2       Archaeopteryx   136      77
3      Confuciusornis   120      41
4         Microraptor   141     119
5           Sapeornis   110      86
6 Scansoriopterygidae   120      85
```

It's a bit odd that the order of the taxa has changed... Is this ok?

In any case, I converted it into a matrix:

```
> all_agg_matrix <- as.matrix(all_agg)
> all_agg_matrix
                 Group.1   Tibia Feather
[1,]          "Anchiornis" "153"    "81"
[2,]       "Archaeopteryx" "136"    "77"
[3,]      "Confuciusornis" "120"    "41"
[4,]         "Microraptor" "141"   "119"
[5,]           "Sapeornis" "110"    "86"
[6,] "Scansoriopterygidae" "120"    "85"
```

And then used the phyl.pca function:

```
> phyl.pca(tree, all_agg_matrix, method = "BM", mode = "corr")
[1] "Y has no names. function will assume that the row order of Y matches tree$tip.label"
Error in invC %*% X : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

So, now the order that the function is considering taxa in is all wrong (but I can fix that relatively easily).  The issue is that phyl.pca doesn't seem to believe that my matrix is actually a matrix.  Any ideas why?

Comment: I think the first error message is fairly clear... what are you using as a tree, can you post it? Code is [here](https://github.com/liamrevell/phytools/blob/master/R/phyl.pca.R), it is just checking number of rows of Y versus `Ntip(tree)`. As for the second part of your question, your matrix should have only numbers yes, not pair of numbers like e.g. `138, 101`. The NAs and NULLs could be an additional problem, but you need to provide a matrix 1st.

Comment: Hi, I've posted the details of the tree. It's a very simple one with a simple progression from Microraptor to Confuciusornis. As for the matrix, how do I then make sure that each "tibia" number corresponds with the appropriate "feather" number if I don't do it in pairs?  Is there some other solution?

Comment: see my edits to my answer.  Don't use `as.matrix` on the whole data frame; it is turning your numeric columns into character strings ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have bigger problems.  Most phylogenetic methods, I suspect including `phyl.pca`, assume that traits are fixed at the species level (i.e., they don't account for within-species variation).  Thus, if you want to use `phyl.pca`, you probably need to collapse your data to a single value per species, e.g. via

```
dd_agg <- aggregate(dd[,-1],by=list(dd$Taxa),mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Extract the numeric columns and label the rows properly so that `phyl.pca` can match them up with the tips correctly:

```
dd_mat <- dd_agg[,-1]
rownames(dd_mat) <- dd_agg[,1]
```

Using these aggregated data, I can make up a tree (since you didn't give us one) and run `phyl.pca` ...

```
library(phytools)
tt <- rcoal(nrow(dd_agg),tip.label=dd_agg[,1])
phyl.pca(tt,dd_mat)
```

If you do need to do an analysis that takes within-species variation into account you might need to ask somewhere more specialized, e.g. the `r-sig-phylo@r-project.org` mailing list ...

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Please see the original post for the changes made according to your suggestions and the new issues...

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by Ben Bolker seems to work whereby the data (called "all") is collapsed into a single value per species before creating a matrix and running the function.  As per so:

```
> all_agg <- aggregate(all[,-1],by=list(all$Taxa),mean,na.rm=TRUE)
> all_mat <- all_agg[,-1]
> rownames(all_mat) <- all_agg[,1]
> phyl.pca(tree,all_mat, method= "lambda", mode = "corr")
```

Thanks to everyone who contributed an answer and especially Ben! :)